# Django restful create api marks a new entry as edited on creation

Tags: python, django-simple-history

I have been working on tracking edit history of comments in my app using django-simple-history, I have been able to track the edited comments but just realized that am also tracking entries upon creation. ie new entries are added to the history table on creation.

my model

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    is_Child = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_rel',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='comments',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='threads')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.body)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

My view class

```
class CommentsListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Comments.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = (CommentJSONRenderer,)

    def create(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_context = {
            'request': request,
            'article': get_object_or_404(Article, slug=self.kwargs["slug"])
        }

        article = Article.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
        data = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=data, context=serializer_context)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user, article_id=article.pk)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Do you not to track the create history? The point of django-simple-history is to serve as a sort of audit log, so that every create, edit, and delete is tracked.

Answer (score 0):

That's part of `django-simple-history` behavior but what you could do is delete that type of records in a [signal](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html) if you do not want to store that information.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from simple_history.signals import (
    post_create_historical_record
)

@receiver(post_create_historical_record)
def post_create_historical_record_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    history_instance = kwargs['history_instance']
    if history_instance.get_history_type_display() == "Created":
        history_instance.delete()
```